# Unable to uninstall MariaDB

Tags: apt, package-management, 15.04, uninstall, mariadb

I tried to re-install MariaDB, I used:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*
```

But the only package remaining to be un-installed after the failed attempted above is `mariadb-server-10.0`.

When I try to purge it using:

```
sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server-10.0
```

I got this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libdbi-perl libterm-readkey-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mariadb-server-10.0*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 74.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 460851 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.23-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.0 (--purge):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 6
Errors were encountered while processing:
mariadb-server-10.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How should I proceed in attempting to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: This might sound counter productive, but try reinstalling MySQL, then removing MariaDB, then removing MySQL in a separate command?

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is a open source version(without any hassles of parent Oracle) of MySQL.
You need to find out from the install logs of MariaDB where MySQL has been installed(it could be under /etc/init.d)
And then stop it

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Once that is done then perform the same action that you are trying to do.

Comment: It still yields the same result.

Comment: @SH4NKZ. Not a very clean or graceful way but you can delete the directories(in recursive manner) being created at the time of installation of MariaDB. It seems installation script couldn't identify whether MySQL is really stopped or not?

Comment: how do I determine which directories is being created at the time of installation of MariaDB?